# Nested HTML tags

Tags: html, css

Having a brain freeze...

I want to do this :

```
<li>
 <a>
  <p>text</p>
  <p class="x">text</p>
 </a>
</li>
```

I know I can't. So how do I ? (No JS/jQuery etc)

Comment: Are you looking for standards compliant? Because you COULD do that.

Comment: "Standards compliant" if you're using HTML 4.01 Transitional, otherwise no. You cannot wrap a block element (*p*) with an in-line element (*a*).

Answer (score 5):

Change `<p>` to some inline element (e.g. `<span>`) and give `li a span` a style of `display: block;`, I guess.

```
<li>
 <a>
  <span>text</span>
  <span class="x">text</span>
 </a>
</li>
```

Comment: Sure. But then it wouldn't be standard compliant because of block inside inline

Comment: @Mike: Styling spans with `display: block` will not cause your HTML to invalidate. It simply tells the browser to *display* your spans as blocks, but according to the markup structure they're still considered inline and will be valid.

Comment: @BoltClock I didn't know that. In which case, that's the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Mike: No problem, we learn something new every day, and here that's what we help each other do :)

Comment: Might want to consider marking this as the correct answer then.

Answer (score 0):

You could do that in HTML(5). But support in some browsers (Firefox) is flakey. See: http://html5doctor.com/block-level-links-in-html-5/

The best way is to use naturally inline elements such as `<span>`s instead of block level elements inside the anchor.

Answer (score 0):

This validates as XHTML 1.1:

```
  <li>
   <p><a href="example.com">text</a></p>
   <p class="x"><a href="example.com">text</a></p>
  </li>
```

Comment: Should validate in most if not all flavors of XHTML 1.0 and HTML 4 and 5 as well.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming what you're getting at is you want the entire block of text in the list item, and maybe the entire list item, to be clickable?

First, a paragraph tag is a block level item, but an anchor tag is inherently an inline element.  You can't place that inside an anchor tag, it's not semantically correct and it won't validate.  Do something like this instead:

```
<ul class="myList">
<li>
  <a href="#">
      <strong>This is the title</strong>
      <span>This is the link text</span>
  </a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Assuming you want the entire area of the list item to be clickable, you can apply display:block; to the anchor tag using css.  Note that if you've assigned a different height to the list item and want everything to be clickable, you'll need to set the height on the  tag as well.

```
.myList a { display:block; }
```

And if you want the strong tag to break a line (your "main text" in the link)...

```
.myList a strong { display:block;}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Cracking answer. Thanks to you as well.